# Randomly displayed flashing lines, no response to all shortcuts, just power off. [syslog included]

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, 9.10, syslog

I have an old machine, and I want to use for that to learn employees how to use Ubuntu, and to be easyer to switch from Windows. I've been installed 10.04, and updated, but this strange stuff is happend. Graphical installion failed, same strange thing. With alternate workd.

Sometimes, when I boot up, a boot message displayed: *Keyboard failure...*, often diplayed after reboot, and after shutdown, when I haven't plugged off from AC. I replaced the keyboard yet, same failure... If I powered off, and plugged off from AC, no keyboard problems displayed in boot time.

**Details**

Configuration:
Dell OptiPlex GX60 - in original cover, no changes.

- 256 MB DDR 166 MHz
- [Intel® Celeron® Processor 2.40 GHz](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=27178)
- Dell 0C3207 Base Board

I know, that is not enough, but I have three other Nec compuers, with nearly similar config, and they works well with 9.10, 10.04, 10.10.

**Live CDs**

I've been tried with 10.04 and 10.10, but the problem is displayed too. With 9.10 no strange things displayed, but it froze, during a simple apt-get install.

**Syslog**

An error loop is logged here, but I paste the whole startup and error lines.
The flashing lines are displayed sometimes immediately after login, but sometimes after 10 minutes, but once occured, that nothing happend.

Strange thing is displayed immediately after login: [here](http://paste2.org/p/1209979).

An other boot, after some minutes, strange lines, and loop in log appeard: [here](http://paste2.org/p/1209985).

The loop should be that:

```
Jan 23 00:20:08 machine_name kernel: [   46.782212] [drm:i915_gem_entervt_ioctl] *ERROR* Reenabling wedged hardware, good luck
Jan 23 00:20:08 machine_name kernel: [   47.100033] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... GPU hung
Jan 23 00:20:08 machine_name kernel: [   47.100045] render error detected, EIR: 0x00000000
Jan 23 00:20:08 machine_name kernel: [   47.101487] [drm:i915_do_wait_request] *ERROR* i915_do_wait_request returns -5 (awaiting 16 at 9)
Jan 23 00:20:11 machine_name kernel: [   49.152020] [drm:i915_gem_idle] *ERROR* hardware wedged
Jan 23 00:20:11 machine_name gdm-simple-slave[1245]: WARNING: Unable to load file '/etc/gdm/custom.conf': No such file or directory
Jan 23 00:20:11 machine_name acpid: client 1239[0:0] has disconnected
Jan 23 00:20:11 machine_name acpid: client connected from 1247[0:0]
Jan 23 00:20:11 machine_name acpid: 1 client rule loaded
```

**UPDATE**
Added syslog things: before errors, error loop, the complete shutdown(after the big updates):

```
Jan 28 20:40:30 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Sucessfully called chroot.
Jan 28 20:40:30 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Sucessfully dropped privileges.
Jan 28 20:40:30 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Sucessfully limited resources.
Jan 28 20:40:30 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Running.
Jan 28 20:40:30 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Watchdog thread running.
Jan 28 20:40:30 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Canary thread running.
Jan 28 20:40:30 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Sucessfully made thread 1337 of process 1337 (n/a) owned by '1001' high priority at nice level -11.
Jan 28 20:40:30 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jan 28 20:40:32 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Sucessfully made thread 1345 of process 1337 (n/a) owned by '1001' RT at priority 5.
Jan 28 20:40:32 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jan 28 20:40:32 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Sucessfully made thread 1349 of process 1337 (n/a) owned by '1001' RT at priority 5.
Jan 28 20:40:32 machine_name rtkit-daemon[1339]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jan 28 20:40:37 machine_name pulseaudio[1337]: ratelimit.c: 2 events suppressed
Jan 28 20:41:33 machine_name AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
Jan 28 20:41:44 machine_name kernel: [  167.691563] lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Jan 28 20:47:33 machine_name AptDaemon: INFO: Quiting due to inactivity
Jan 28 20:47:33 machine_name AptDaemon: INFO: Shutdown was requested
Jan 28 20:59:50 machine_name kernel: [ 1253.840513] lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Jan 28 21:17:02 machine_name CRON[1874]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 28 21:17:38 machine_name kernel: [ 2321.553239] lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Jan 28 22:07:44 machine_name kernel: [ 5327.840254] lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Jan 28 22:17:02 machine_name CRON[2665]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 28 22:32:38 machine_name sudo: pam_sm_authenticate: Called
Jan 28 22:32:38 machine_name sudo: pam_sm_authenticate: username = [some_user]
Jan 28 22:32:38 machine_name sudo: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/some_user is already mounted
Jan 28 22:57:03 machine_name kernel: [ 8286.641472] lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Jan 28 22:57:24 machine_name sudo: pam_sm_authenticate: Called
Jan 28 22:57:24 machine_name sudo: pam_sm_authenticate: username = [some_user]
Jan 28 22:57:24 machine_name sudo: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/some_user is already mounted
Jan 28 23:07:42 machine_name kernel: [ 8925.272030] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... GPU hung
Jan 28 23:07:42 machine_name kernel: [ 8925.272048] render error detected, EIR: 0x00000000
Jan 28 23:07:42 machine_name kernel: [ 8925.272093] [drm:i915_do_wait_request] *ERROR* i915_do_wait_request returns -5 (awaiting 171453 at 171452)
Jan 28 23:07:45 machine_name kernel: [ 8928.868041] [drm:i915_gem_idle] *ERROR* hardware wedged
Jan 28 23:08:10 machine_name acpid: client 925[0:0] has disconnected
Jan 28 23:08:10 machine_name acpid: client connected from 8127[0:0]
Jan 28 23:08:10 machine_name acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Jan 28 23:08:11 machine_name kernel: [ 8955.046248] [drm:i915_gem_entervt_ioctl] *ERROR* Reenabling wedged hardware, good luck
Jan 28 23:08:12 machine_name kernel: [ 8955.364016] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... GPU hung
Jan 28 23:08:12 machine_name kernel: [ 8955.364027] render error detected, EIR: 0x00000000
Jan 28 23:08:12 machine_name kernel: [ 8955.364407] [drm:i915_do_wait_request] *ERROR* i915_do_wait_request returns -5 (awaiting 171457 at 171452)
Jan 28 23:08:14 machine_name kernel: [ 8957.472025] [drm:i915_gem_idle] *ERROR* hardware wedged
Jan 28 23:08:14 machine_name acpid: client 8127[0:0] has disconnected
Jan 28 23:08:14 machine_name acpid: client connected from 8141[0:0]
Jan 28 23:08:14 machine_name acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Jan 28 23:08:15 machine_name kernel: [ 8958.671722] [drm:i915_gem_entervt_ioctl] *ERROR* Reenabling wedged hardware, good luck
Jan 28 23:08:15 machine_name kernel: [ 8958.988015] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... GPU hung
Jan 28 23:08:15 machine_name kernel: [ 8958.988026] render error detected, EIR: 0x00000000
Jan 28 23:08:15 machine_name kernel: [ 8958.989400] [drm:i915_do_wait_request] *ERROR* i915_do_wait_request returns -5 (awaiting 171459 at 171452)
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name init: tty4 main process (848) killed by TERM signal
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name init: tty5 main process (856) killed by TERM signal
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name NetworkManager:   nm_signal_handler(): Caught signal 15, shutting down normally.
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name init: tty2 main process (874) killed by TERM signal
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name init: tty3 main process (875) killed by TERM signal
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name init: tty6 main process (877) killed by TERM signal
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name init: cron main process (890) killed by TERM signal
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name init: tty1 main process (1146) killed by TERM signal
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name avahi-daemon[644]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name avahi-daemon[644]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.238.11.134.
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name acpid: exiting
Jan 28 23:08:16 machine_name init: avahi-daemon main process (644) terminated with status 255
Jan 28 23:08:17 machine_name kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Jan 28 23:09:00 machine_name kernel: imklog 4.2.0, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jan 28 23:09:00 machine_name rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.2.0" x-pid="516" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
Jan 28 23:09:00 machine_name rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Jan 28 23:09:00 machine_name rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Jan 28 23:09:00 machine_name rsyslogd-2039: Could no open output file '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
```

When I hit the On/Off button, the system shuts down normally.

May be it a hardware problem, but I don't know...

**Can you say something useful to solve my problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are having issues wit your intel graphics card.

The first thing I would try is making sure all updates are done and you're running 10.04.2

If that doesn't help, then installing 10.10, which has it's own set of different intel issues but not the ones you have here. I had a machine with a similar issue and the only way to get it working was to use 10.10.

Good luck!

Comment: In addition to the docs diagnosis it seems to be an issue with KMS (kernel mode setting). I had to completely disable it for my laptop with an old ATI chip. There is a bug here at launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/541492?comments=all which could be similar to your problem and as you can see by the number of duplicates and heat you would not be the only one with this problem.

Comment: @Martin Owens -doctorm, thanks, my bad, because I ran **apt-get upgrade**, and I just realized that it doesn't installs kernel updates, I changed to **apt-get dist-upgrade**, and it upgrades everything.
After kernel update, everything seems to be good.
@Allan thanks your comment

Comment: Sorry Martin, I have the lastest updates, and the flashing thing is now appears after long hours. I think, with kernel updates, I only euthanised this problem.

Comment: @Allan, I saw that bugreport, and I try to triage it :)

Comment: @B. Roland - Yes, this is the same experience I had. Please upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: @Martin, you say, that the only way is 10.10? No triages & updates are possible? And what about the set of different issues with intel graphic cards? Which are these problems on your system? *question updated*

Comment: @B. Roland - This issue is that the intel driver can't be updated without updating both the kernel and the xorg system. which is a major system upgrade. I suspect that the bugs were fixed, but not in time for those releases... sorry.

Comment: @Martin so, I'll try to upgrade to 10.10, and I'll write the results, thanks your comments!

Comment: Hmm, I think with the lastest 10.10 there are no flashing lines, but it has higher X.org load; If I don't do anything, the system has nearly 0.40 load, and X.org is in the first line - shown by *top*. @Martin, can you help in this problem too?

Comment: Not in this question, please post a new question otherwise this one will get unwieldy.

Comment: right, thanks your support! I think I'll put in a new memory module, and improve the memory!